# How to give another column's value to a table function's argument? (or, Snowflake copy_history with multiple table_names)

Tags: sql, function, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-function, information-schema

I want to run [Snowflake's copy_history function](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/copy_history.html) to a long list of table names. I have a table (LOAD_TABLES) with one column (TABLE_NAME) which contains all those table names.

[image]

Now I want to apply the copy_history function with all those table names, but the function takes in the table_name argument as a string, so it seems I can't pass it a list of names like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COPY_HISTORY (TABLE_NAME => (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM LOAD_TABLES ))
```

If so, I'm thinking of JOINing the function's results to the LOAD_TABLES like this:

```
SELECT * FROM LOAD_TABLES
LEFT JOIN SELECT * FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COPY_HISTORY (TABLE_NAME => LOAD_TABLES.TABLE_NAME))
```

But this gives an `SQL compilation error: invalid identifier`

How can I apply this function to a bunch of different table names at once? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

out of curiosity, why can't you just use the LOAD_HISTORY View? Because the function isn't really made for bulk use and I'm not sure what you're trying to do makes sense.

at the same time making a
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/info-schema/load_history.html
query you can just tailor it the way you want (maybe using union if a single select goes over the 10k rows limitation - but 10k rows is really plenty)

Comment: Right now the table with load histories is created by calling the copy_history function hundreds of times, each time with a different table name (and UNIONing all these function results together). I'm just looking for a simpler way to do this. The LOAD_HISTORY view in that same db's INFORMATION_SCHEMA is empty.

Comment: have you tried submitting that as a bug to support? Because based on the documentation it sounds like it's what you should be using....

Comment: @MMW one of the issue with LOAD_HISTORY is it does't has history of data loaded using Snowpipe